# Access Thread from inside Runnable

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, thread-sleep

How can I access `Thread` object that is executing given `Runnable`? What I'd like to do is to call `sleep()` from within `run()` method.

Comment: Sleep is static, there is no way to *sleep* an arbitrary thread... unless you own the OS stack.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you need to sleep within a `Runnable`, you can simply call `Thread.sleep();` inside the `run` method.

To access the thread that is running the `Runnable`, you can call `Thread.currentThread()`, but that is not necessary to call the `sleep` method, which is static.

Comment: yes, I should have guessed it'd be so trivial. Thanks for help anyway.

Comment: Not necessary is too generous. It's not legal since you can not call sleep on a thread instance through a thread reference. You can only sleep your current thread through the static Thread.sleep();

Comment: Well technically you can but it will still sleep the current thread.

Answer (score 7):

you can always get the current `Thread` that your code is executing within by calling the static method `Thread.currentThread()`.

But in your case, you don't need the thread itself because sleeping is controlled with the following static method:

```
Thread.sleep(1000L);
```